# Command Prompt in Windows: How to create a batch file called LS to function like DIR?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This should a relatively easy thing to do but my mind has shifted away from creating batch files for a very long time. I am on a win7 machine and using cmd (command line prompt). What I want to do is to type 'ls' instead of 'dir' as a command. 
Example:

```
c:\ls
 Volume in drive U is Users
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXX

 Directory of c:\

02/06/2015  03:19 PM    <DIR>          .
02/06/2015  03:55 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/06/2015  03:17 PM    <DIR>          public
               X File(s)         XXXXXX bytes
               X Dir(s)  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX bytes free
```

I've made a batch file called 'ls.bat' in the directory of 'C:\Windows\System32' and i can call 'ls' from the command prompt but nothing is output.
*I think I created one like this before in the past but I'm getting old.*

ls.bat contains the following:

```
dir
```

Let me know if there's a need for more clarification. :)

**Q: What do I need script in my batch file to function like 'dir' when I call 'ls' ?**

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you _sure_? Is there anything else in your path environment variable directories (`echo %path%`) that is also called `ls`?

Comment: FYI, you can simply enter the command `doskey ls=dir` and that's all.

Comment: only one thing missing: passing any parameters to `ls.bat`: `@dir %*`

Comment: Unrelated: but putting stuff into `system32` is very bad idea. Create a directory where you collect all your utility batch files and add that to the `PATH`. What you have described should work nevertheless. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Jon: to process parameters with the `doskey`solution: `doskey ls=dir $*`

Answer (score 1):

All you need in your .bat file is `dir %cd%`

If I had more rep I would post this in a comment so mod if you can please do.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script named `ls.cmd`

in the `ls.cmd` file write following

`@echo off
dir /B`

put the directory of script in PATH variable.

enjoy :)

You may explore more options like `dir /W`

Just type `dir /?` and explore :)